# Android youtube-api cancels FLAG_FULLSCREEN in Activity

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

i have designed my application to work in fullscreen mode. No status bar and no action bars are visible. This suppose a problem since every time a load a video from youtube ussing YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI the status bar appears.

My activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_open_translate,R.anim.activity_close_scale);

    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if(getActionBar()!=null) {

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fad_socios);
    ...
}
...
private void changeFragment(int index) {

    switch(index) {

        case 0:{
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FADFragment(),"informacion").commit();
            break;
        }
    ...
}
```

The way i refer YoutubeAPI indide my fragment:

```
            fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentz, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    portadaFrag.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if(buttonSelected == 0) {

                        ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).playingYoutube=true;

                        fragment.initialize(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.youKEY), new OnInitializedListener(){

                            @Override
                            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

                                Log.e("fail","fail");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2) {

                                youtubePlayer = arg1;

                                youtubePlayer.loadVideo("-D-MVgOvvOo");

                                youtubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new PlaybackEventListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {

                                        try {
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).refreshWindow();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {}
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPaused() {

                                        try {
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).playingYoutube=false;
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).refreshWindow();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {}
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPlaying() {

                                        try {

                                            youtubePlayButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).playingYoutube=true;
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).refreshWindow();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {}
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {

                                        try {
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).refreshWindow();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {}
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStopped() {

                                        try {

                                            youtubePlayButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).playingYoutube=false;
                                            ((FADSociosActivity) getActivity()).refreshWindow();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {}
                                    }

                                });
```

My refreshWindow method inside the first activity:

```
public void refreshWindow() {

    try {

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Using this method im able to force the activity to be in fullscreen mode again after a little and undesirable tilt of the status bar. Anyway, every time the user taps over the video, the activity exits fullscreen mode. It seems that YoutubePlayer-API is overriding my FLAG_FULLSCREEN and i can't avoid this. Anyone knows how to overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, setting the flag YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION after initialization seems to solve the problem =)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to reset all the flags in onInitializationSuccess, to never show the status bar at all:

```
player.setFullscreenControlFlags(-1);
```